# Which function should I use to filter the records in EF with max

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am trying to convert my Db Query in EF.

**DB Query**

```
Select isnull(max(ReceiptNo), 0) as ReceiptNo from tblReceipt where CompanID = 2
```

**EF Code**

```
var result = db.tblReceipts.Max(i=> i.ReceiptNo);
```

My question is: Which function should I use to filter the records where `companyID = 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ReceiptNo` is a nullable long? Then you could use:

```
long result = db.tblReceipts
    .Where(r => r.CompanID == 2)
    .Select(r => r.ReceiptNo ?? 0)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(long.MinValue)
    .Max();
```

If the max `ReceiptNo` of all records with `CompanID == 2` was `NULL` you'll get 0 as result, if there was no record with that ID you'll get `long.MinValue`, otherwise you'll get the max value.